# autocomplete text box

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsp, servlets

i want to make a text box like stackoverflow have for the tag at askquestion page where data pop up as we write something.
I want to fetch the tag from the database rather local static data.
In my project i am using jsp servlet hibernate and spring
Please tell me how to do..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend below jquery plugin. You can use multiple autocomplete textbox easyly.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

Comment: thanks friend but the problem it value that pop up to textbox takes only static data written in array. I want value to pop up from the database.. 
help me.

Comment: jquery not supports taking query from database and displaying the result http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not writing it but rather use one of JSF-based frameworks such [as RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) But if you do want to do it yourself - web is full of tutorials on how to do it [such as this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html)